# RegExp: Get text within parentheses

Tags: python, regex

I'm using Python's Regular Expression module, and I'm trying to extract a section of multi-line text wrapped between parenthesis. Here is some example text:

```
function name1 (
    arg1,
    arg2,
    arg3
);

function name2 (
    arg1,
    arg2,
    arg3
);
```

The following pattern does work, but its always finding the last closing parenthesis (function name2) and not the first:

```
re.findall('(?<=\()(.*)(?=\))', text, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
```

How can I modify the pattern, so that the first closing parenthesis is matched?

Comment: note that regex is not good for recursive searching, so beware if you have functions within functions, or parenthesis within parenthesis, ie. calls to other functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your regex to this, notice the `?` after `*` makes it a non-greedy search:

```
>>> re.findall('(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\))', text, re.MULTILINE | re.DOTALL)
['\n    arg1,\n    arg2,\n    arg3\n', '\n    arg1,\n    arg2,\n    arg3\n']
```