# Groovy regexp linebreak within parentheses

Tags: regex, grails, groovy

I need to delete a paragraph enclosed within parentheses like below, without touching the rest of the text as below

```
(Text to delete Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur linebreak->
in voluptate velit esse cillum. Excepteur sint proident, mollit anim id est laborum.)

Text that shouldnt be touched Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation  llamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehend in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat  upidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```

For now I have `/\(.*\)[\n]*/` to match a pragraph, but with the linebreaks, it obviously doesn't work. I was thinking about something in the lines of `/\(.*[\n]*\)[\n]*/` but that didn't work. Looking [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21536156/regexp-get-text-within-parentheses) results with `(?<=\()(.*?)(?=\))` but its python, so won't work, and other links are about parentheses within parentheses, so that's different from my problem.

The `\n` is to simplify the `(\r|\n|\r\n)` linebreak thing.

So is there a way to do it, or is the regexp in groovy not capable of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use something like `/(?s)\(.+?\)/` (example available [here](https://regex101.com/r/rT4uM5/1)), which according to [here](http://www.ngdc.noaa.gov/wiki/index.php/Regular_Expressions_in_Groovy) makes the period character also match new line feeds.

The expression will look for round brackets and stop at the first occurrence of a close bracket.